# 11ty Pass template data to a syntax highlighted tag

Tags: eleventy, prismjs

So, I've got a template that brings data from a collection, this specific collection has info about some fonts, and I need to output a block of syntax highlighted code, this code references how the font should be added using `@fontface` for example:

```
           {% highlight css %}
            @font-face 
                font-family: coolFont;
                src: url(/fonts/coolFont.woff) format("woff"),
              url(fonts/coolFont.ttf) format('truetype');
                  font-weight: normal;
                font-style: normal;
                font-display: swap;
            }
            {% endhighlight %}
```

I'm looking to pass the font name from the post front matter and have it output with the loop for every one, however, since it renders as `<code>` it outputs my liquid tags, instead of the front matter data.

```
            {% highlight css %}
            @font-face 
                font-family: {{ post.data.fontName }};
                src: url(/fonts/{{post.data.fontName}}.woff) format("woff"),
              url(fonts/{{post.data.fontName}}.ttf) format('truetype');
                  font-weight: normal;
                font-style: normal;
                font-display: swap;
            }
            {% endhighlight %}
```

Is there a way to "escape"  the brackets??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may be interested in [this issue](https://github.com/11ty/eleventy-plugin-syntaxhighlight/issues/35) from the `eleventy-plugin-syntaxhighlight` Github repo.

Essentially, Liquid templating inside the `{% highlight %}` tags don't work, but you can work around it by either switching to Nunjucks templating (where templating will work inside the block) or by defining a [custom paired shortcode](https://www.11ty.dev/docs/shortcodes/#paired-shortcodes) where you use Prism or your highlighter of choice directly.